# php foreach in static function

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop in a `static` function. But for some reason it only does one loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
static function printall(){
    foreach (self::$products as $product){ 
        return print_r($product); 
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 700152
    [1] => 21.0000
    [2] => 5.2000
    [3] => 24.7900
)
```

But when I print_r the self::$products I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 700152
            [1] => 21.0000
            [2] => 5.2000
            [3] => 24.7900
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 700000
            [1] => 21.0000
            [2] => 3.4700
            [3] => 16.5200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 705300
            [1] => 21.0000
            [2] => 1.3900
            [3] => 6.6100
        )    
)
```

Comment: **return** stops the method.

Comment: Stupid stupid stupid, Thanks! Knew it would have been something dumb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `return` statement terminates the function by returning a value, so the loop only runs for one iteration. Just drop it and you should be fine:

```
static function printall(){
    foreach (self::$products as $product){ 
        print_r($product); 
    }
}
```